# How to transfer specific value from one page to another?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, font-awesome

I have two pages the first is called store.php and the other cart.php. I try to transfer the total rows number from a table from the page cart.php on the store.php page that I have the cart icon and i put the number of products above it. My idea was through javascript count all rows in the table and place it on the cart icon. The problem is as much as try I can not get the value of all rows from the page cart.php inside to store.php.

```php
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

        <title>store</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

            <div class="Cart">

                <a href="cart.php">

                    <i class="fa fa-shopping-cart" aria-hidden="true"></i>

                    <span class="Cart_Number" id="Cart_Number"></span>

                </a>

            </div>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="Counter_Cart.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

```php
<html>

    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="main.css">

        <title>cart</title>

        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.4.1/css/all.css">

        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>

            <table style="width:100%" id="Product_Map">
                <tr>
                    <th>Product name</th>
                    <th>Quantity</th> 
                    <th>Price</th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product 1</td>
                    <td>Product 1</td>
                    <td>Product 1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Product 2</td>
                    <td>Product 2</td>
                    <td>Product 2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>Nothing</td>
                    <td>Nothing</td>
                    <td>Total</td>
                </tr>
            </table>

         <script type="text/javascript" src="Counter_Cart.js"></script>

    </body>

</html>
```

```
function CountRowsUsingJavascript() {

    var totalRowCount = 0;

    var table = document.getElementById("Product_Map");

    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");

    for (var i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {

        if (i > 0) {

            totalRowCount++;

        } else {

            totalRowCount = 0;

        }

    }

    if (totalRowCount > 0) {

        totalRowCount = totalRowCount - 1;

        return totalRowCount;

    } else {

        return totalRowCount;

    }

}

var Value_For_The_Cart = CountRowsUsingJavascript();
```

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question, I can think of two ways this can be done:

#### Window.name

`window.name` is sort of a special variable that will keep its value across page reloads and navigation, as long as the user stays on the same tab. This variable only takes strings so you could convert your number to a string.

```
window.name = Value_For_The_Cart.toString();
```

#### Local storage

Local storage is used for storing data that persists in the user's browser, and thus is kept across pages. To save something to local storage you would do

```
localStorage.setItem('whateverNameYouWant', Value_For_The_Cart.ToString());
```

And to get it

```
localStorage.getItem('whateverNameYouWant');
```

But I advise you to consider if handling this client side is the best way to go about this.